# SSRS URL Change

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am struggling with getting SSRS to have a domain name without naming the virtual directory. To give an example.

I currently have reporting.domain.com/reports working fine. It's great. However, I want to eliminate the /reports, and I want to use reports.domain.com.

I have tried to google this, but I haven't found any instructions on getting this done.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do? This is for INTERNAL purposes and not public web purposes.

Reiteration:

reporting.domain.com/reports (currently works fine)
to
reports.domain.com (I want end users to use this)

Comment: I've never tried to do this but what is the web portal address set to in "Reporting Services Configuration Manager"?

Comment: It's set to http://reporting:80/reports

Answer (score 0):

You can enable IIS on the SSRS box and have it forward http://reports.domain.com to https://reports.domain.com/reports.

See eg https://www.sqlservice.se/how-to-redirect-ssrs-url/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, the above answer was close but just off base.

Install IIS Services.

Create a website with the name you want.

Create a page called Default.htm and make it a HTML document. Input the HTML meta code to redirect to another website.

Create a DNS record for your website, and it should work.

Using an HTTP Redirect built into IIS will not work with the SSRS stuff, must use the HTML meta code.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="delay_time; URL=new_website_url" />`